# Views grid output is top-to-bottom, not left-to-right?

Tags: views

I have a view outputting a grid of fields sorted by title, however the sorting is not what I expected:

What i'm getting:

```
A  D  G

B  E  H

C  F  I
```

What I want:

```
A  B  C

D  E  F

G  H  I
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need to change the display of your grid from horizontal to vertical or vice-versa. You may also have to play with the "fill up single line setting". [image]

Comment: Woohoo! I was hoping it was that simple! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, glad that worked!